# Goland failed to sync go mod dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

After upgarding to 2021.3 for MAC, my goland can't sync go mod dependencies from internet.  No matter if I double clicked missing dependency in my go source file or go.mod, I can't find sync dependencies option.

I tried to sync go mod via project structure view, but nothing showed up in event log.

How do I resolve this issue?

[image]
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong with goland itself.  This issue happened after I switched my git branch several times, due to each branch has different go.mod content, this bug was triggerred.

I deleted .idea folders and invalid cache via File->invalid cache and restart.

After that, goland was able to fetch go.mod dependency again.

Comment: Is _.idea_ directory fully in _.gitignore_?

Comment: i deleted my .idea directory and it started working again.